# Dijkstra's Algorithm length

Tags: pseudocode, dijkstra

from [this website's](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/dijkstra.html) pseudocode:

```html
Given a graph, G, with edges E of the form (v1, v2) and vertices V, and a
source vertex, s

dist : array of distances from the source to each vertex
prev : array of pointers to preceding vertices
i    : loop index
F    : list of finished vertices
U    : list or heap unfinished vertices

/* Initialization: set every distance to INFINITY until we discover a path */
for i = 0 to |V| - 1
    dist[i] = INFINITY
    prev[i] = NULL
end

/* The distance from the source to the source is defined to be zero */
dist[s] = 0

/* This loop corresponds to sending out the explorers walking the paths, where
 * the step of picking "the vertex, v, with the shortest path to s" corresponds
 * to an explorer arriving at an unexplored vertex */

while(F is missing a vertex)
   pick the vertex, v, in U with the shortest path to s
   add v to F
   for each edge of v, (v1, v2)
        /* The next step is sometimes given the confusing name "relaxation"
        if(dist[v1] + length(v1, v2) < dist[v2])
            dist[v2] = dist[v1] + length(v1, v2)
            prev[v2] = v1
            possibly update U, depending on implementation
        end if
    end for
end while
```

what is meant by: *if(dist[v1] + length(v1, v2) < dist[v2])*?

particularly: *length(v1, v2)*.

shouldn't: *dist[v1] < dist[v2]* enough?

Comment: the invariant is that `dist[i]` contains the smallest distance of `i` from source. so whenever you set `dist[j]` from `i` you're interested in how far `j` is from the source, and that is `dist[i] + length(i,j)`

Comment: `dist[i] < dist[j]` is not enough to state that you can reach vertex `j` from `i` faster than it (i.e. vertex `j`) was reached from some other vertex

Answer (score 0):

`length(v1, v2)` is the weight of the edge from node v1 to v2.

This condition checks whatever the path to v2 can be improved by going to v1 and then through edge (v1,v2).